# The entered digits are not organized in a matrix properly

Tags: java

I wrote some code but the output is not exactly what I want. The result is okay, but the first two matrices are not. So, when I input numbers in the first and second 2x2 matrix it does not organize properly in the array.

**My code is:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i, j;


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter 4 digits in the first matrix:");

    int arrey1[][] = new int[2][2];
    int arrey2[][] = new int[2][2];
    int sum[][] = new int[2][2];

    for (i = 0; i < arre1.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arrey1.length; j++) {
            arrey1[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Enter 4 digits in the second matrix:");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            arrey2[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            sum[i][j] = arrey1[i][j] + arrey2[i][j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The result is:");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            System.out.print(sum[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

**I would need this outcome:**

```
Enter 4 digits in the first matrix:
1 2
3 4
Enter 4 digits in the second matrix:
5 -1
3 -4
The result:
6 1
6 0
```

Thank you very much the help is advance.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to StackOverflow. What to do you mean by 'not arranged properly' ? I ran your code and it is giving correct output.

Comment: Why do you call your example as matrix? I didn't read your code, just the example input and desired output. It seems to me that you entered two arrays or lists with the same length (size), and your output is another array or list with the sums of appropriate elements. **Edit** This comment was posted before your edited question...

Comment: Hi @PraveenE :) when I enter numbers in the first and second 2x2 matrix it does not organize properly in an array (in a 2x2 shape), just in a line.

Comment: Please don't change your question in such a way that it invalidates existing answers.

Answer (score 2):

Your code worked fine for me.

The only problem was your first loop after the array declarations, you have a typeo `arre1` instead of the variable you declared `arrey1`. I assume that means you retyped this into your question, instead of copy/paste?

Also, `arrey` is incorrectly spelled. The correct way to spell it is `array`. Not that it makes a difference in your code. It's just a spelling tip.

Here is a screenshot of the numbers for your anticipated outcome.

[image]

Comment: You can even press Enter after the `2` and the `-1` to make it look exactly like OP wanted.

Comment: @Andreas yeah I just tried to keep the picture as small as possible. I guess two extra lines wouldn't have made it much bigger lol.

Comment: Hello guys! :) I edited my question but the problem is still the same. When I enter the first 4 digits (and then the 2nd 4 digits), the result will be a line, but I would need a 2x2 matrix as in the example.

Comment: @HuserB1989 can you post your own screenshot of the result? Everything works fine with what you have. I don't understand what you're asking. I also updated my picture to reflect the exact output you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Visual arrangement is not at all related to your outcome. All that matters is the logic of your program.

If you want input to look like array, type in the following way
Enter 4 digits in the first matrix: 1 2 3 4 (Press Enter)

Enter 4 digits in the second matrix:
5 -1 (Press Enter) 3 -4 (Press Enter)